# Is there a way to stop the nouveau timeout error from occurring during install via bootable USB for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, usb-installation, nouveau

I have been trying create a dual-boot system on my new Windows desktop but keep getting a blacked out screen just after the OS installation process for Ubuntu starts. I briefly get to see the purple screen with the welcome and second after I get a black screen prompting a timeout error regarding nouveau drivers.  After some research I've arrived to the conclusion that it had to do with my GPU (Nvidia RTX 3090).  I've read the solutions are to install the drivers via sudo apt-get but how can I do that if the OS isn't even installed?

Comment: You can use the "Try Ubuntu (safe graphics)" option or use `nomodeset`. Make sure Secure Boot is disabled in uEFI (unless you intend to dual-boot with Windows 11) and then during the Ubuntu installation be sure to mark the option to install 3rd party drivers. The required Nvidia drivers will be automatically installed.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for the help.  I tried the first option you suggested (running the installation under safe graphics) and it worked perfectly.